# Normalisation in Harmonic Oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, coherent-states

For a harmonic oscillator, I can write

$$
|\alpha \rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2}|\alpha|^2} \Sigma_n \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle = \sum_n\langle n|\alpha\rangle|n\rangle
$$

I can also write:

$$
|x \rangle = \sum_n\langle n|x\rangle|n\rangle
$$

Is the expression $\sum_n\langle n|x\rangle\langle x|n\rangle$ equal to one or delta function?

Here $\alpha$ is coherent state and $x$ is position.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Note that your question basically only asks whether $\langle x | x \rangle$ is equal to one or $\delta(0)$; you defined a coherent state but it is unclear how it is connected to your question.

Comment: `<n|x>` is hermite polynomial `H_n`. the question basically becomes is `\sum_n H_n^2` equal to one or delta function

Comment: If you want to understand the sum $\sum_{n=0}^N ⟨x'|n⟩⟨n|x⟩$ for *finite* $N$ (and then the limit as $N$ increases), you might find [this paper of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5724) interesting.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thanks. will check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_n\langle n |x\rangle\langle x|n\rangle&=\sum_n\langle x|n\rangle\langle n |x\rangle\\
&=\langle x|\left(\sum_n\langle n|n\rangle\right)|x\rangle\\
&=\langle x||x\rangle\\
&=\langle x|x\rangle\\
&=\delta(x-x)=\delta(0)
\end{align}
To see why this normalisation is the case consider the identity operator in the x-basis.
$$=\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|$$
Squaring the identity operator must result in another identity operator so
\begin{align}
^2&=\left(\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|\right)\left(\int dy|y\rangle\langle y|\right)\\
&=\int dx\,dy |x\rangle\langle x|y\rangle\langle y|\overset !=
\end{align}
If we plug in $\langle x|y\rangle=\delta(x-y)$ we get the desired answer
\begin{align}
\int dx\,dy |x\rangle\langle x|y\rangle\langle y|&=\int dx\,dy |x\rangle\langle y|\delta(x-y)\\
&=\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|=
\end{align}

Comment: `<n|x>` is hermite polynomial `H_n`. so you are basically saying that \sum_n H_n^2  is equal to delta function?

Comment: @curious Almost. I think the relation you are looking for is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness_relation which says $\sum_n\psi_n(x)\psi_n(y)=\delta(x-y)$ where $\psi_n(x)$ are related to the Hermite polynomials according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions. I don't know much about Hermite polynomials so I can't help you beyond this.

Comment: @curious $\langle n\vert x\rangle$ is not a Hermite but $e^{-x^2/2}$ times a Hermite.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks. so the question becomes: is $\sum_n e^{-x^2} H_n^2=\delta(0)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The expression
$$\sum_n\langle n|x'\rangle \langle x|n\rangle =\langle x|x'\rangle =\delta(x-x')=\delta_{x'}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_n\langle n|x'\rangle \langle x|n\rangle=\delta_x=\infty$$

Comment: why should $\delta_x=\infty$?